# How to only get one axis to track

Tags: tracking

So I hope in the scene below it is very obvious what I am trying to do. I basically want to have cutout models always track to my empty BUT ONLY on the Z Axis.

I want 1 empty to control an entire scene full of cutouts ( keep in mind I want these cutouts in many different locations along the z axis ).

This way when I setup a shot I can just have my empty attached to my camera and all 200 cutouts just rotate on the Z axis no matter where they are along it.

Hope that makes sense, and thank you everyone!!!

[image]

Comment: Use "Locked Track" constraint with locked Z axis

Comment: You nailed it friend! That is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Serge_L Can you help me with this question please? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163003/animation-nodes-how-to-make-an-object-face-camera-yet-let-the-object-rotate-ar